# Autocomplete jQuery only works after browser restart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using jQuery Autocomplete in ASP.NET MVC4.
The first time I try the autocomplete, it won't work. (setted breakpoint in controller, but no hits)
Then I restart the browser and everything works fine.
This is my code:

```
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <input type="search" name="Gemeente" class="ui-autocomplete" placeholder="Gemeente" />
    </div>



  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.ui-autocomplete').autocomplete({
                source: '@Url.Action("../RelatieZoeken/AutocompleteGemeenten")',
                minLength: 2,
                delay: 10
            });
        });
    </script>



public ActionResult AutocompleteGemeenten(string term)
    {
        List<string> items = new List<string>();

        items = _zoekClient.GetGemeenten();

        List<string> filteredItems = new List<string>();

        filteredItems = items.Where(test => test != null && test.ToLower().StartsWith(term.ToLower())).Take(5).ToList();

        return Json(filteredItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the **minLength = 1**:

minLength : The minimum number of characters a user has to type before the Autocomplete activates. Zero is useful for local data with just a few items. Should be increased when there are a lot of items, where a single character would match a few thousand items.

Eg.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.ui-autocomplete').autocomplete({
                source: '@Url.Action("../RelatieZoeken/AutocompleteGemeenten")',
                minLength: 1,
                delay: 10
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: good to know: Even if I just set a .Focus(), it doesn't execute the first time I run the page. minLenght:1 doesn't work.